# Is DateTimePicker cannot disable past time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to disable past time and date based on my selection of start date and end date. I was able to disable my date, but it won't work on time.

**Example:**

```
Start Date  - 24-May-2019 01:30 PM
End Date    - 24-May-2019 01:00 PM < suppose to not be able to choose an earlier time
```

i tried this function, but while disable past date is working fine, still cannot for time

```
onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
    var endYear = $(this).datetimepicker('getFullYear');
    var endMonth = $(this).datetimepicker('getMonth');
    var endDay = $(this).datetimepicker('getDate');
    var endHour = $(this).datetimepicker('getHours');
    var endMinutes = $(this).datetimepicker('getMinutes');
    var endSeconds = $(this).datetimepicker('getSeconds');
    ("#endDate").datetimepicker("option", "minDate", new Date(endYear, endMonth, endDay, endHour, endMinutes, endSeconds));
}

onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
    var endYear = $(this).datetimepicker('getFullYear');
    var endMonth = $(this).datetimepicker('getMonth');
    var endDay = $(this).datetimepicker('getDate');
    var endHour = $(this).datetimepicker('getHours');
    var endMinutes = $(this).datetimepicker('getMinutes');
    var endSeconds = $(this).datetimepicker('getSeconds');
    $("#startDate").datetimepicker("option", "maxDate", new Date(endYear, endMonth, endDay, endHour, endMinutes, endSeconds));
}
```

also tried this function below, but also not working

```
onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
    $("#endDate").datetimepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    $("#endDate").datetimepicker("option", "minTime", selectedDate);
}

onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
    $("#startDate").datetimepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    $("#startDate").datetimepicker("option", "maxTime", selectedDate);
}
```

**current working code (that disable past date only):** 
for start date

```
onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
  $("#endDate").datetimepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
}
```

**WORKING CODE**
added an onClose function to read the time 
*for example :* 
if user select start date *05-May-2019 5:00 AM* and end date *05-May-2019 3:00 AM* 
the start date value will automatically update to *05-May-2019 3:00 AM*

for end date

```
onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
  $("#startDate").datetimepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
}
```

for startDate

```
onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
    var startDateSelect = $('#startDate');
    var endDateSelect = $('#endDate');

    if (endDateSelect.val() != '') {
        var sDate = startDateSelect.datetimepicker('getDate');
        var eDate = endDateSelect.datetimepicker('getDate');
        if (sDate > eDate)
            endDateSelect.datetimepicker('setDate', sDate);
    }
    else {
        endDateSelect.val(dateText);
    }
},
onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
    $("#endDate").datetimepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
}
```

for endDate

```
 onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
    var startDateSelect = $('#startDate');
    var endDateSelect = $('#endDate');

    if (startDateSelect.val() != '') {
        var sDate = startDateSelect.datetimepicker('getDate');
        var eDate = endDateSelect.datetimepicker('getDate');
        if (sDate > eDate)
            startDateSelect.datetimepicker('setDate', eDate);
    }
    else {
        startDateSelect.val(dateText);
    }
},
onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
    $("#startDate").datetimepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using jquery DateTimePicker, there are option for setting the min/max time as well.

use minTime or maxTime for times
use minDate or maxDate for dates

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/qy48so6d/1/

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    minDate:'2019/05/01',
    maxDate:'2019/05/02',
    minTime:'01:00',
    maxTime:'02:00'
  });
```

Reference: https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#minTime

---

If you are using https://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

you can try this

```
$("#endDate").datetimepicker("option", "minDateTime", selectedDate);
// or
$("#endDate").datetimepicker("option", "minTime", '8:00 am');
```

Example

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var startDateTextbox = $('#startDate')
  var endDateTextbox = $('#endDate')
    startDateTextbox.datetimepicker({
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            endDateTextbox.datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', startDateTextbox.datetimepicker('getDate'))
      endDateTextbox.datetimepicker('option', 'minTime', '8:00 am')
      endDateTextbox.datetimepicker('option', 'maxTime', '9:00 am')
    }
  });
  endDateTextbox.datetimepicker({
    minTime: '8:00 am'
  });
})
```

Comment: I try it like this, but not working onSelect: function `(selectedDate) {
 $("#upDate").datetimepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
 $("#upDate").datetimepicker("option", "minTime", selectedDate);
}

onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
 $("#downDate").datetimepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
 $("#downDate").datetimepicker("option", "maxTime", selectedDate);
}`

Comment: why you put inside onSelect? min/max should be set during initialization

Comment: i want to set the changes based on selection. example: if i select startDate 24-May-2019 10:00 AM, i want to set endDate to disable all past time, so user if user select 24-May-2019, they cannot select time under 10:00 AM

Comment: can you share which datetimepicker you are using?

Comment: that's a different library. they dont have onSelect as mentioned

Comment: i cant find which library you are using. the `onSelect` option is not found

Comment: based on the link above, there are options called `minDateTime` or `maxDateTime`. you can try that

Comment: try that, not working... if I use `onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
  $("#endDate").datetimepicker("option", "minDateTime", selectedDate);
}` and `onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
  $("#startDate").datetimepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
}` if i select date and time on startDate, for endDate, the time disappear

Comment: error on textbox for selecting time vanish pic > https://ibb.co/BBzCT2p

Comment: thanks for your help, i am able to make it work with our discussion. i will update the working code later.